# error installing cocoa pods

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I'm trying to install the Datetools pod. The new workspace was created for me. But when I went to finish installing it and typed "pod install" I received this message in my terminal:

"[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `catfever3` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-catfever3/Pods-catfever3.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-catfever3/Pods-catfever3.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration."

So obviously I need to do one of those 2 things so that the pod can work in my project. At first I tried option 2 ("include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-catfever3/Pods-catfever3.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration"). I went to Project--> build settings and project--> build phases and searched the word "configuration" but got 0 results. So where exactly in my build settings do I go in order to change this?

thanks

Comment: Did the proposed answer work for you? How did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming your project is named "CocoaPodDemo"...*

In the workspace, in the **Project Navigator** (leftmost pane), select your project, i.e. CocoaPodDemo.
In the **Project & Target List** (center pane), under PROJECT, select your project again.

[image]

Under Info > Configuration > select each target and pick the Pod-CocoaPodDemo.debug and Pods-CocoaPodDemo-release respectively.

[image]

Note that once you are in the situation you describe, it does not hurt to close the Xcode project, and execute:

```
rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install
```

and reopen the workspace